# How to enable/disable a item in a QTreeView eventbased?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, signals-slots, qtreeview

I want to enable/disable a checkable item in a QTreeWidget, when a specific signal is sent.

The following code dows not work:

```
model = QStandardItemModel()
view = QTreeView()
view.setModel(model)
rootItem = QStandardItem()
rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()

categoryItem = QStandardItem(item)
categoryItem.setCheckable(True)
rootItem.appendRow(categoryItem)

signalSource.availabilityChanged.connect(categoryItem.setEnabled)
```

It produces the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'PySide.QtGui.QStandardItem'
```

Is there a solution for changing the state or data of a QStandardItem via signal/slot?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback and the definition of `signalSource`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in PySide, as `connect` should accept any callable (the example code works correctly in PyQt4).

As a workaround, try wrapping `QStandardItem` methods in a lambda:

```
signalSource.availabilityChanged.connect(
    lambda enable: categoryItem.setEnabled(enable))
```

**EDIT**

To connect the items in a loop, use a default argument, like this:

```
for button in buttonList:
    item = QStandardItem("Test")
    ...
    button.toggled.connect(
        lambda enable, item=item: item.setEnabled(enable))
```

Comment: @leviathan. See my updated answer for how to use `lambda` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of ekhumoros answer, I found a way to get my problem solved, but it seems to be an ugly workaround in PySide, using the sender to get the signal hooked up correctly.

```
import sys
import argparse
import signal

#import sip
#sip.setapi('QString', 2)
#from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QTreeView
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QTreeView


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
              QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

              buttonList = []
              for i in xrange(10):
                  button = QPushButton("1")
                  button.setCheckable(True)
                  buttonList.append(button)

              model = QStandardItemModel()
              view = QTreeView()

              view.setModel(model)

              layout = QVBoxLayout()
              self.setLayout(layout)

              buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
              layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)

              for button in buttonList:
                  buttonLayout.addWidget(button)

              layout.addWidget(view)

              rootItem = QStandardItem()
              rootItem = model.invisibleRootItem()

              self.itemList = {}
              for button in buttonList:
                  item = QStandardItem("Test")
                  item.setCheckable(True)
                  rootItem.appendRow(item)
                  self.itemList[button] = item

                  # Works with PyQt4, but not with PySide
                  #button.toggled.connect(item.setEnabled)
                  # Workaround for PySide
                  button.toggled.connect(self.workaround)

              for button in buttonList:
                  button.setChecked(True)


          def workaround(self, enable):
              self.itemList[self.sender()].setEnabled(enable)


def main(argv):
    app = QApplication(argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    retcode = app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Just using a lambda construct didn't work in the loop. It just connect all the signal with the last reference to iterate over.